# Need help in filtering the email id in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-7

I have a log which has been retrieved from the web server. As I'm new to the Elasticsearch I have a problem in writing the DSL query. The issue is I need to retrieve the email id from log and visualize it on my kibana dashboard.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show the DSL query you're trying, the mapping of your index and also a sample document that you're trying to match? In other words: Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build this query in the GUI. I don't think you'll even need to transform the data in any way, since you only need a simple string, which is the default data type for most pipelines.

Under visualize, create a new visualization and choose your style of choice. The first data field should be able to be populated with your email field.

Depending on your visualization type, you may have to build a bucket before the visualization shows the data that you expect. You'll have to treat this like a dependency and determine what aggregation you might need to use first.